# Marlin "Tune->Bed Z" vs "Tune->Babystep Z" vs Z Offset?

Tags: z-axis, print-axis-offset

What is the difference between:

- Tune -> Bed Z
- Tune -> Babystep Z
- Control -> Motion -> Z Offset

And when are you supposed to use "Bed Z"?

Answer (score 7):

- Tune -> Bed Z

http://marlinfw.org/docs/features/lcd_menu.html#tune

Per description in this table, this refers to the Mesh Bed Leveling process. It allows to modify all saved mesh z-offsets by the given amount.

- Tune -> Babystep Z

http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M290.html

This just instructs the motor to move the given amount, once, without changing any parameters.

- Control -> Motion -> Z Offset

http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M851.html

Here we are talking about the offset of a z probe (e.g. BL-Touch) from the nozzle.

Comment: Nice overview! Noteworthy might be that the parameters under "Tune" are only available during printing, so it is to adjust settings during printing.